# Weird result returning conditional CASE WHEN value from apoc.do.when

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

We have following graph

[image]

where gray nodes (:Conversation) represent conversations between users (:User pink nodes). I created query that tries to find current conversation between people and if it does not exist then create it. In both cases conversation must be returned.
Here is its code:

```
MATCH (u1:User {login:"User_1"})
MATCH (u2:User {login:"User_2"})
MATCH (u3:User {login:"User_3"})

OPTIONAL MATCH
    (conv:Conversation)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u1),
    (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u2),
    (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u3)
WHERE NOT EXISTS { 
    MATCH (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u:User)
    WHERE NOT u IN [u1, u2, u3]
}

CALL apoc.do.when(conv IS NULL, 
    "WITH $u1 AS u1, $u2 AS u2, $u3 AS u3 " +
    "CREATE (conv:Conversation) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u1) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u2) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u3) " +
    "RETURN conv AS conv",
    "RETURN $conv AS conv", {u1:u1, u2:u2, u3:u3, conv:conv}) YIELD value
[...WEIRD PART...]
```

Explanation: 
**OPTIONAL MATCH** - tries to find current conversation between User 1,2,3 - conversation **71** and **72**
**WHERE NOT EXIST** - exclude other conversations between these Users where others may be included like **User_4** - **72**
We end up with only one conversation we are interested in: **71**
...and now the weird part comes in **[...WEIRD PART...]**

If we replace **[...WEIRD PART...]** with code

```
RETURN value.conv
```

everything is fine, but before I came up to this solution I was struggling with other code, where in the apoc mapping **conv:conv** was not included and **else-query** was just **""**

```
WITH CASE WHEN conv IS NULL THEN value ELSE conv END AS conv
RETURN conv
```

that part was creating new conversation between these users 1,2,3 every time we run the query.
However if I replaced it with just

```
RETURN value
```

it was working correctly, by which I mean it did not create new conversation between users 1,2,3 if it existed.

**ISSUE: I do not understand why following code**

```
MATCH (u1:User {login:"User_1"})
MATCH (u2:User {login:"User_2"})
MATCH (u3:User {login:"User_3"})

OPTIONAL MATCH
    (conv:Conversation)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u1),
    (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u2),
    (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u3)
WHERE NOT EXISTS { 
    MATCH (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u:User)
    WHERE NOT u IN [u1, u2, u3]
}

CALL apoc.do.when(conv IS NULL, 
    "WITH $u1 AS u1, $u2 AS u2, $u3 AS u3 " +
    "CREATE (conv:Conversation) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u1) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u2) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u3) " +
    "RETURN conv",
    "", {u1:u1, u2:u2, u3:u3}) YIELD value

WITH CASE WHEN conv IS NULL THEN value ELSE conv END AS conv
RETURN conv
```

**could be responsible for such weird behavior.**

Comment: Just so we can be clear on what was tried, can you show the entirety of the segment that wasn't working as a whole? The cut-and-paste description here isn't bad (the WEIRD PART stuff), but I'd like to see the full thing to better see if something was missed somewhere.

Comment: I just edited the Question and added full query causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug  with the name spacing of existential subqueries. Since `conv` is reused to mean something else, Cypher rewrites all but the last two `conv` to `conv@x` and the last two to `conv@y`, in order to distinguish between them. Here x and y are the positions of the first occurence of `conv` with a specific meaning. This rewriting was not properly propagated to the inner subquery.

It has been fixed here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/2890463ad6d2f323bfbad5cf453f14b42f51c830 and will be included in the next patch release of Neo4j 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification, I can reproduce this, and it's definitely not expected. This looks like a bug to me.

We can circumvent the issue by renaming the alias used with your CASE to be `conv2` or anything other than `conv`. This should work:

```
MATCH (u1:User {login:"User_1"})
MATCH (u2:User {login:"User_2"})
MATCH (u3:User {login:"User_3"})

OPTIONAL MATCH
    (conv:Conversation)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u1),
    (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u2),
    (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u3)
WHERE NOT EXISTS { 
    MATCH (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u:User)
    WHERE NOT u IN [u1, u2, u3]
}

CALL apoc.do.when(conv IS NULL, 
    "WITH $u1 AS u1, $u2 AS u2, $u3 AS u3 " +
    "CREATE (conv:Conversation) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u1) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u2) " +
    "MERGE (conv)-[:CONDUCTED_BY]->(u3) " +
    "RETURN conv",
    "", {u1:u1, u2:u2, u3:u3}) YIELD value

WITH CASE WHEN conv IS NULL THEN value ELSE conv END AS conv2
RETURN conv2
```

I'll raise this with our engineers to confirm and start on a bug fix.